# Qual é o jeito mais simples de fazer um IS NULL com o Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Vi tutoriais na internet que a forma que você tinha para fazer um `IS NULL` é a seguinte:

```
Remessa::where('campo', 'IS', DB::raw('NULL'))->get();
```

Porém eu fiquei me questionando sobre isso, pois se um ORM geralmente é desenvolvido pensando em criar uma maneira de consultar os dados que sejam compatíveis com todos SGBDs.

Apesar de funcionar, creio que a forma destacada acima não seja essencial.

Com o `Eloquent`, existe algum método (sem ser o destacado acima) que eu possa fazer  um `where` fazendo a condição `IS NULL` ou `IS NOT NULL`?

Creio que dessa maneira atual acaba ficando repetitivo.

Comment: Eu estou lendo na internet sobre Eloquent e Fluent. Mas as vezes me deparo com situações que preciso usar Fluent.

Comment: É a mesma coisa, exceto que no `Fluent` você inicia a query com `DB::table` ao invés do Model

Comment: Particularmente, detesto o fluente. Para mim, quem programa em Laravel deveria usar o Model, que é a abstração, onde você pode configurar os relacionamentos e afins. O Fluent  já não faz isso, ele é para fazer queries mais "cruas", como se faz no CodeIgniter

Comment: Sim. Eu também não gosto de usar Fluent.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Sim, existem dois métodos; um que você pode usar para o `IS NULL` e outro para `NOT NULL`.

seguem os exemplos:

Para `IS NULL` você pode utilizar

```
Remessa::whereNull('campo')->get();
```

Você também pode fazer de uma maneira, onde poderá passar vários `IS NULL` de maneira mais simples:

```
  Remessa::where(['campo' => NULL, 'usuario_id' => NULL])->get();
```

e para  `NOT NULL`

```
Remessa::whereNotNull('campo')->get();
```

Para ver os resultados que são gerados pelas consultas, você pode usar o método `toSql` no final para testar.

```
 Remessa::where(['campo' => NULL])->toSql();
```

A saída será:

```
SELECT * FROM remessas where (campo IS NULL)
```